# Self Made Arduino Morse Code Library Stops After First Letter

Tags: c++, loops, arduino

I am trying to write an Arduino Library that easily outputs Morse code on a digital pin. I followed a tutorial but then tried to add a bit myself. When I compile and upload my code to the arduino, it compiles fine with no errors but when it gets run on the arduino, it properly outputs the first letter and then stops.

here is my .ino file:

```
#include <Morse.h>

Morse morse(13);

void setup()
{
  morse.writeStr("Wow");
  delay(3000);
}

void loop()
{

}
```

and here is my library header file (.h):

```
/*
  Morse.h - Library for flashing Morse code.
  Created by Adrian Wowk, December 11, 2019.
  Released into the public domain.
*/
#ifndef Morse_h
#define Morse_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class Morse
{
  public:
    Morse(int pin);
    void dot();
    void dash();
    void writeStr(char message[6]);
  private:
    int _pin;

};

#endif
```

and here is my library C++ file:

```
/*
  Morse.cpp - Library for flashing Morse code.
  Created by Adrian Wowk, December 11, 2019.
  Released into the public domain.
*/

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Morse.h"

Morse::Morse(int pin)
{
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    _pin = pin;
}

void Morse::dot()
{
    digitalWrite(_pin, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(_pin, LOW);
    delay(250);
}

void Morse::dash()
{
    digitalWrite(_pin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(_pin, LOW);
    delay(250);
}

void Morse::writeStr(char message[6])
{
    for (byte i = 0; i < sizeof(message) - 1; i++)
    {
        switch (message[i])
        {
        case 1:
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 2:
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 3:
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 4:
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 5:
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 6:
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 7:
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 8:
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 9:
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 0:
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'a':
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'A':
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'b':
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'B':
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'c':
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'C':
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'd':
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'D':
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'e':
            dot();
            break;
        case 'E':
            dot();
            break;
        case 'f':
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'F':
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'g':
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'G':
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'h':
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'H':
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'i':
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'I':
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'j':
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'J':
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'k':
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'K':
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'l':
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'L':
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'm':
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'M':
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'n':
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'N':
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'o':
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'O':
            dash();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'p':
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'P':
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'q':
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'Q':
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'r':
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'R':
            dot();
            dash();
            dot();
            break;
        case 's':
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'S':
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 't':
            dash();
            break;
        case 'T':
            dash();
            break;
        case 'u':
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'U':
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'v':
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'V':
            dot();
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'w':
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'W':
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'x':
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'X':
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'y':
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'Y':
            dash();
            dot();
            dash();
            dash();
            break;
        case 'z':
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case 'Z':
            dash();
            dash();
            dot();
            dot();
            break;
        case ' ':
            delay(250);
            break;

        default:
            delay(1000);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: afaik arduino is some C++ dialect, in any case it is not C **and** C++

Comment: `sizeof(message)` print that out.

Comment: try (sizeof(char) * 6) instead of sizeof(message) in your for-loop

Comment: I tried printing it out and it had the correct size.

Comment: What value did you get and did you read the link?

Comment: i used (sizeof(char) * 6) and it worked thank you, but how would i do this if I didn't know the size of the string being passed through

Comment: I read the link but didn't really understand it fully

Comment: pass the size of the string with the string or you can also (sometimes) get the size of a string with sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0])

Comment: could you please explain

Comment: Use `String` and not a char array. Then use [`String length`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringLength).

Comment: that works too^^^^ yeah didn't think about that if you aren't writing c why not just use String??

Comment: ok so how would i use that in my scenario

Comment: So basicamente the reason I wanted you to do sizeof(char)*6 is because referencing 'message' in your function is the same as referencing &message[0] which is the size of your char pointer in bytes. You want the size of the actual string not the pointer to the first char @Wowkster

Comment: ok i see,  so would it still be better to use the String.length() if i didn't know the size of the string being passed?

Comment: yes the String class (which I am pretty sure Arduino has their own String class) will keep track of your string length for you so you will never need to try to calculate/remember it just call .length on it. It may not be a function it could be a member so you may have to call .length not .length()

Comment: ok thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your **Morse::writeStr** function there is a problem. Doing **sizeof(message)** should throw the following error:

```
warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'message' will return size of 'char*'
```

You cannot find the actual length of the message by looking at the size of *message* in the way you do. The variable *message* in your **writeStr** function is passed as a pointer to the char array, the size of the pointer is equal to 1.

Next to this you're iterating from `i = 0` to `i < sizeof(message) - 1`. Since the size of *message* **IS** 1, you're iterating from `i = 0` to `i < 0` and the for loop should not even execute once.

Next to the pointer to the char array, you should also pass the length of the array and use that in in your for loop. For example like so:

```
void Morse::writeStr(char *message, int size_)
{
    for (char i = 0; i < size_; i++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Remember to also change this function declaration in your header file. Then, in your **loop** or **setup** function you can send a char array to the function like this:

```
Morse morse(13);
char msg[] = "test";
morse.writeStr(msg, 4);
```